Question regrding path analysis structure/variable representation?
I am trying to do a path analysis to evaluate the effects of a seeding treatment (5 different species) on different types of ground cover (native, non-native, and seeded species), which in turn, has an impact on soil erosion.  I am not sure whether the seeding treatment should be grouped into a single variable (B), or separated out into individual factor levels (A)? Thanks!


Since the treatment/species variable appears to be nominal/qualitative, you would have to include the treatment/species variable as multiple dummy code variables, specifically, one dummy code variable less than you have species. That is, you would create 5 - 1 = 4 binary (0 vs. 1 coded) variables with one species as reference category and include the four binary dummy code variables as independent variables in your path model. Pretty much any regression textbook will tell you how to do this, for example:
Cohen, J., Cohen, P., West, S. G., & Aiken, L. S. (2013). Applied multiple regression/correlation analysis for the behavioral sciences. Routledge.
Likewise, your mediator variable(s) also appear(s) to be nominal, so you would have to take this into account by proper coding as well and use a logistic regression link function in your model since the mediator(s) is/are binary. This is doable (i.e., in software capable of handling multivariate logistic regression and path models such as Mplus) but it complicates the analysis. I recommend taking a look at the literature on mediation analysis with binary mediators:
https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=mediation+with+binary+mediator&oq=mediation+with+binary+

I don't know if makes a difference, but I will be coding this with the lavan package in R.

Analysis of nominal outcomes is not among the lavaan features (only binary/ordinal outcomes): https://lavaan.ugent.be/about/features.html
